# mail composer. Removing keyboard explicitely?

Tags: iphone, email, iphone-softkeyboard

how to resign keyboard explicitly for mailcomposer view controller.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution. we have to get all sub views of keywindow and check for keyboard. if you found key board than we can resign it.